# How can I execute multiple C# functions from a single clientside EndCallBack to update more than one DevExpress Gauge control?

Tags: c#, devexpress

I would like to update 4 gauges when someone filters the ASPxGridView table below them. I have added the appropriate javascript function calling the custom callback function on each gauge but if I try doing more than one gauge, it fails.

On the aspx page I have the following and it works great and is almost instantaneous:

```
<ClientSideEvents EndCallback="function(s, e) {
reportGaugeFirst.PerformCallback(s, e);
} "  />
```

When I try adding another gauge, it fails or takes a LONG time:

More than 2 and it never returns (the gauges just display "Loading" over them forever).

The contents of one of the procedures is as follows:

```
protected void reportGaugeLTD_CustomCallBack(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
ASPxGridView gridView = reportGridUnit as ASPxGridView;
float Miles = (float)Convert.ToDouble(gridView.GetTotalSummaryValue(gridView.TotalSummary["MilesLTD"]));
float Fuel = (float)Convert.ToDouble(gridView.GetTotalSummaryValue(gridView.TotalSummary["FuelLTD"]));
LTDMPGValue = Miles / Fuel;
ArcScaleComponent scale = GetGaugeScale(reportGaugeLTD, 0, 0);
scale.Value = LTDMPGValue;
scale.Ranges.Clear();
scale.Ranges.Add(CreateRange(globals.colorGaugeRedRange, 0, 3));
scale.Ranges.Add(CreateRange(globals.colorGaugeYellowRange, 3, overallMPGGoal));
scale.Ranges.Add(CreateRange(globals.colorGaugeGreenRange, overallMPGGoal, 10));
}
```

I have four gauges in total but they all have the same core code.
I've also tried calling one function from another function in a chain but even though the calculations all check-out and the value updates, the only the first gauge refreshes and shows the value.

Answer (score 0):

The solution here was to use an ASPxCallbackPanel and fire the OnCallBack event on that. Inside the callback panel are the four gauges I wanted to update.

Now that they're in a single collection/panel, they can all be accessed and updated.